# Python ValueError - Extracting a float from a matplotlib axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a function whose formula changes at a specific value (mn), but I can't figure out how to compare the value of the x axis with this number to determine which formula to use.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mn = 10312054216.046213
mz = 91.1876
a1z = 98.330
a2z = 29.571
a3z = 8.396
b1, b2, b3 = -13/(4*pi), 19/(12*pi), 7/(2*pi)
b1p, b2p, b3p = -157/(36*pi), 11/(12*pi), 17/(6*pi)
c1, c2, c3 = 3/5, 1, 1

ms = np.linspace(100, 10e18, num = 100, endpoint = True)

def a1(ms, mn):
    if (ms < mn):
        return ( c1*(a1z + b1*np.log(ms/mz)) )**(-1)
    if (ms >= mn):
        a1n = ( c1*(a1z + b1*log(mn/mz)) )**(-1)
        return ( c1*(a1n + b1p*log(ms/mn)) )**(-1)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(ms, 1/a1(ms, mn))

plt.show()
```

Just using ms > mn gives

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

How can I extract the current value being used for ms when a1 gets called?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to calculate, but the comparison `if (ms < mn)` fails because when you call the function as

```
plt.plot(ms, 1/a1(ms, mn))
```

then `ms` is a numpy array and `mn` is a number, and you can't compare those two. If instead you want to plot the value of `a1` for each individual *element* from `ms`, then you could try this:

```
plt.plot(ms, [1/a1(x, mn) for x in ms])
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that method does what I needed.